# How can I run my console JS codes everytime?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My college online education website has a dark mode but my choice is not memorized. And they hadn't changed that since it started. I can change that via Chrome console by `themebase.replace("light", "dark")` but I want it run when I started the website every time.

I tried to create a file named yildiz.html

```html
<script>
   window.location.href="https://online.yildiz.edu.tr/";
   alert("test");
   themebase.replace("light", "dark");
</script>
```

As you can imagine, the rest of the code doesn't run when `href` changes.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) to run your script continuously. Otherwise, your code will not work if you change the URL or refresh it. Install the extension and create a new script. Change `@match` as follows to match your URL and all of its pages -

```
// @match        https://online.yildiz.edu.tr/*
```

Now write your script where you are told to write your own code.

Comment: Thank you so much, Understood. I am studying it.